# Oracle WHERE clause performance

Tags: database, oracle

I have a statement similar to ;

```
SELECT tableA A, tableB B, tableC C
WHERE a.ID = b.ID and 
C.level = '2'
```

If i perform

```
SELECT tableA A, tableB B, tableC C
WHERE a.ID = b.ID and
```

My results are returned in 33 seconds. If i perform the original query the results are returned in 150 seconds. Why does `C.level = '2'` make it slower?

Comment: Your statement does not correctly join all three tables. You are missing at least one join condition. You should get used to using an explicit `JOIN` instead of doing the joining in the where clause.

Comment: It's also missing the `from` clause: Presumably these have been omitted for the sake of brevity.

Comment: How are you measuring how long the query takes?  Until the first row is returned or until all rows are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Oracle's execution plan, you'll see what it's doing under-the-hood. However, to summarise, my guess is that your logic is:

> By adding `C.level = '2'`, we should be getting a smaller dataset which should therefore be returned faster

However, for the database engine, it now has to go through the data and check each record to see if it matches your more complicated condition. How it does this is determined by your schema. For example, if you have an index on `c.level`, that may make the performance difference negligible.

Comment: assuming that cannot do indexing, is there a way to restructure the query to perform faster?

Comment: Your query is very simplistic, there's very little that could be done to it: whether that would make it faster, or not, is besides the point. Why can you not create indexes?